# Is there an entire function which is not a polynomial such that $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{f\left(z\right)}{z}=\infty $

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm wondering if there's an entire function $f$ which is not a polynomial such that $\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{f\left(z\right)}{z}=\infty$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would you like f(x) = Exp(x) ?

Comment: @Claude Then $\frac{f(x)}x\to 0$ alnong the negative reals.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen. I suppose I missed something. Sorry fot that. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your hypotheses imply that $f(z)/z$ is everywhere meromorphic on the Riemann sphere, and is thus a rational function.

The only affine singularity is at zero, so the denominator of $f(z) / z$ must be a power of $z$.

But because $f(z)$ is entire, the denominator of $f(z) / z$ cannot have more than one factor of $z$, and thus $f(z)$ is a polynomial.